# Azure: How to add >1TB disks to a virtual machine without changing the size of VM

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I see there are some limitations on Azure:
1. On number of disks to be attached to VM;
2. The size of each disk/storage blob is limited by 1TB;

Is there any hack or workaround to attach larger disks/several disks to the same VM without increasing the processing power of VM as my application doesn't need high computing capacities, but needs plenty of space. 
May be it's possible by contacting their billing department?

Currently I'm using A1 Standard VM instance with 2 disks (2 TB it total) attached to it already. The goal is to attach 5 TB total disk space to the same VM without upgrading the VM size to a larger instance.

Comment: How is this related to programming? What VM type do you currently have? Did you check the available types?

Comment: This is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: two disks per core is the limit (so, up to 64 attached disks), and the 1TB limit is the actual size limit of a page blob. You can go beyond 1TB by creating a striped volume. Also: this isn't the place to be posting price-comparisons - this is a programming q&a site.

Comment: There is no price comparison, where do you see comparing the prices?
It's a general question on how to attach a larger disk or more than 2 disks per 1 core on Azure and if there exists any hack for it. The hack could be of any kind. It's simple with Amazon EC2, but not as simple with limitations on Azure.
I use A1 (1 core, 1.75MB memory) VM and it's absolutely enough for my project requirements. I don't want to spend more on spare computing power.
Is the question clear enough now?

Comment: I'm referring to your comments about how Azure is "forcing to pay more" for resources. No need for any of that commentary, and is unrelated to the technical issue (which, in turn, is not programming-related). Also: Please don't put additional clarification in comments when it's pertinent to the question; edit your question. Nowhere do you mention the amount of storage required (yet you now mention an A1 as a gating factor, but in a comment instead of in the question).

Comment: Ok, apologies for that. I've done that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your VM size to attach more disks. One option is to look at Basic tier instead of using Standard tier A Series VMs to optimize your cost. Since you do not need a lot of computing power, basic tier VMs may work fine for you. You will want to look at Basic A3 which will allow you to attach 8 maximum data disks of 1 TB each. See more information here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-size-specs/)

Thanks,
Aung

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to attach 5TB folders as Azure File Sharing service.
It's possible via creating File Sharing containers through Azure Portal, then mounting the folder under Linux via CIFS (SMB3.0).
For those who are interested, there is an issue with mounting Windows File Sharing folders within CentOS 6.X under Azure. It works only with CentOS 7.X (keep it in mind).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storage Spaces in Azure to increment capacity and performance. The limit of the VHD is 1 TB per disk, using Storage Spaces you can pass this limitation. You need to have in mind that there is a limitation of disk to attach to the VM based on type you choose.

Sample explanation on:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dfurman/2014/04/27/using-storage-spaces-on-an-azure-vm-cluster-for-sql-server-storage/